# how to change magento 2 open source from developer to default, and how do i get back in to my dash?

Tags: magento2, aws

I changed it to default mode by using this path /apps/magento/htdocs/app/etc/env.php (i am using AWS Lightsail, this is why my path is different)
then find where it says developer, and change it to default.

'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',

I checked in on my SSH and it says Default

now that i have done that and i type my instance ip in the browser... I still can't get into my Magento 2 opensource dash.

Is there another way?

this is what it says when when i try to open magento dash by typing my IP address in the url:
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Thank you

Comment: You can check What expception it fired at : /apps/magento/htdocs/var/report.

Comment: got it Just Flush cache on ssh

thank you for all your help. 

for AWS====   sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento cache:flush

thank you.

Comment: If you found the answer, please up rate my above comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change magento mode from either env.php or cli, after changing the mode you have to clear following folders too :

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

But best way is to change mode using cli as it performs all related actions to set magento mode, You can find all helping material on magento docs here :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html